# Grafana templates for Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus, grafana-templating

I am trying to update the node-exporter-full Grafana dashboard with some of our internal labels as templates.  We have labels for "pod" and "servertype" which can be used to get a subset of "nodes" to list at the top of the dashboard.

I can add "pod" like:

```
label_values(pod)
```

Then I can reference "pod" in the node query as follows:

```
label_values(node_boot_time{job="clients",pod="$pod"}, instance)
```

This works.  If I want to add servertype in the middle how would I pull a list of "servertype" based on "pod" which is selected?

I already know the "node" can be filtered with:

```
label_values(node_boot_time{job="clients",pod="$pod"},servertype="$servertype", instance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was pretty simple once I reread the documentation.  Using "up" function currently and it is working fine but there may be a better solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

node_boot_time has been changed to node_boot_time_seconds

Refer to this link to get all the name changes since prometheus 0.16.0
https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues/830

Comment: What do you mean by add some descriptions? I have clearly told that metric which he was using has been renamed. Additionally I have also provided link to refer extra name changes/